# How to add numbers to a folder name

Tags: ruby, generator, directory, identification

I'm working on making a new social network using ruby, and have made a lot of progress. I want to establish new folders that store the users stored within the server. With each folder, I want to add a numerical id to the end of the name, For instance, "users301", or "users557". Would I have to add an input command at the end of the name, or create a folder generator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Dir` library. You would use string interpolation to insert numbers into the string.

You can get the number of users using ActiveRecord. It would look something like this.

```
num_users = User.count
for i in 1..num_users
  Dir.mkdir("users#{i}")
end
```

Of course, the code would have to be updated if a new user was created. You could use a `callback` for that.

```
after_create do
  Dir.mkdir("users#{User.last.id}")
end
```

Comment: Think maybe `User.all.length` is unnecessary, you could just use `User.length`. Can someone confirm?

Comment: You'd probably want `User.count`, that essentially does a `select count(*) from users` whereas `User.all.length` loads all the users into an array so that you can use `Array#length`. I'd probably also use the user's `id` for the number instead of a count, rows can get deleted so there's no guarantee that, for example, `users6` won't get used twice or that `users11` will be associated with user 11.